# NextJS: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, react-component

Using Nextjs and I've created an index.js in the /pages directory and created meta.js in the /components/meta/ directory.

As my app rebuilds I get the following error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.

As seen below I am importing Meta correctly, it is also a default export. Curious where I'm going wrong.

**pages/index.js**

```
// import Head from 'next/head'
import Meta from '../components/meta/meta';

export default () => (
  <div>
    <Meta />
    <p>Hello world! Welcome to</p>
    <h1>Moonholdings.io</h1>
  </div>
)
```

**components/meta/meta.js**

```
import Head from 'next/head'

export default () => (
  <Head>
    <title>Moonholdings.io</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Your Cryptocurrency Portfolio" />>
    <meta name="keywords" content="cryptocurrency, crypto, portfolio, bitcoin, ethereum, holdings"/>
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
  </Head>
)
```

Project structure

[image]

Comment: I am getting the same error on my next.js app but none of the solutions below applied nor worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah just figured it out, was a small typo.

`<meta name="description" content="Your Cryptocurrency Portfolio" />>`

After removing the extra `>` in my meta.js file, it worked.

Answer (score 18):

I got the same error when importing **"Link" with Curly Braces "{}"** from **"next/link"** and using **`"<Link></Link>"`** as shown below:

```js
import { Link } from 'next/link';

const Hello = () => {
  return (
    <Link href='/hello'>
      Hello
    </Link>    
  )
}

export default Hello;
```

So, I imported **"Link" without Curly Braces "{}"** then the error was solved:

```js
// "{}" are removed from "Link"
import Link from 'next/link';

const Hello = () => {
  return (
    <Link href='/hello'>
      Hello
    </Link>    
  )
}

export default Hello;
```

Comment: This totally worked man.
I was having issues displaying an SVG image with the Nextjs "Image" component, didn't realize I was getting that error because I import the Next Image component with curly braces.
So, taking the curly braces out, solved the problem.

Comment: noiche. giving me headache for the last hour.

Comment: This worked for me. I guess the [next.js documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/mdx#getting-started) is wrong then because it uses curly braces.

Answer (score 15):

I ran into the same error because the IDE's auto-import feature can only import the `Head` component from `next/document`.

**Don't:**

```
import { Head } from 'next/document';
```

This `Head` component is to be used in [custom documents](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document).

**Do:**

```
import Head from 'next/head'
```

This `Head` component is to be used in your [pages](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/head).

**Why doesn't my IDE import the correct Head component?**

It's not your IDE's fault. Well, not exactly... the `next/head` component uses a default export. Default exports don't play well with auto-import. It's among the reasons why default exports are considered bad practice. Quite unfortunate that Vercel chose to allow them in their project.

Comment: I ran into exactly this. Maybe worth underlining that the 'next/document' import comes from https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document.

When following react2025.com I had put my title there, gotten a https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-document-title error, then tried to move it back to app but got the imports mixed up.